# Передать один список в другой список, затем обновить второй список при изменении первого?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, шаблоны-проектирования

Знаю, что мой вопрос скорее всего некорректно сформулирован, но я не смог его по-другому выразить:

Есть два списка: lst1, lst2. В lst2 мы сохраняем lst1 посредством метода .extend(). А затем изменяем lst1.

Задача в том, чтобы при изменении lst1, эти изменения сразу переносились и в lst2. Как это можно реализовать?

Вот пример кода:

```
lst1 = []
lst2 = [2, 5]
lst1.append(func_rand_num)
lst2.extend(lst1)

lst1[0] = lst1[0]() # мы изменяем lst1
```

Затем мы ожидаем, что изменится lst2...

Comment: `.extend()` добавляет копию. `.append(lst1)` добавит ссылку. При изменении в lst1 будет меняться и соответствующий элемент lst2 (но видимо вас интересует не это)

Comment: Вы лучше сформулируйте исходную задачу. Зачем вы пытаетесь добиться такого поведения? Если из интереса - это одно, если с какими-то практическими целями - это другое. Может быть это нужно решать вообще по-другому.

Comment: @CrazyElf просто, из интереса.

Comment: Ну тогда да, надо добавлять ссылку на список, а не сам список